# How to get random rows in inner join using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using following queries to fetch random rows,

'`SELECT * FROM TABLENAME1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`' . this query will return random rows.But i need to get the name which is placed in another table.so here i have to use join queries.

'`SELECT tablename1.*,tablename2.name FROM tablename1 INNER JOIN tablename2 ON tablename1.id = tablename2.id ORDER BY RAND(tablename1.id)`'

The above queries return same rows everytime, I am not getting random rows.Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAND(tablename1.id)` uses `tablename1.id` as the seed for the pseudorandom number generator, so it will give you the same result every time. Try just using `RAND()` in your second query.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you're seeding the 2nd version of the query with `tablename1.id`. 
Calls to RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.